# How do I merge multiple cvs files into one DataFrame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a folder with a lot of csv-files each containing messurements of signal data. They have the following structure:

```
Frequency [kHz],Power [dbm]
852000,-135.812845793404
852008,-142.13849097071088
852016,-138.21218081816156
852024,-137.32593610384734
852032,-139.464539680863
```

I want to merge these files into a DataFrame with Frequency as the key column, because the frequency is the same in every file. So it should look something like this in the DataFrame:

```
Frequency [kHz] | Power [dbm] | Power [dbm] | Power [dbm] | ...
```

So I wrote the following code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in csv_files:
    csv = pd.read_csv(f)
    df = pd.merge(df, csv, on='Frequency [kHz]', sort=False)
```

But the only thing I get is an `KeyError: 'Frequency [kHz]'`

The closest I came to my desired result was through `pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_files], axis=0, sort=False)` but then there are still those Frequency columns in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can collect them all as dfs, and then merge, like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

data_frames = []
for f in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    data_frames.append(df)

df_merged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['Frequency [kHz]'],
                                            how='outer'), data_frames)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read them all into a dictionary and use concat:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = 'path' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

df_dict1 = {}

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df_dict1.update({f'{filename}':df})

df = pd.concat(df_dict1, axis =1)
df = df.droplevel(0, axis =1)
df.index = df['Frequency [kHz]']
df.drop(columns = 'Frequency [kHz]', inplace = True)
```

Comment: Now I'm getting in every column `{freq},{pow}`

Comment: df.droplevel(0, axis =1)

Comment: Still the same result. First there are the filepaths, then multiple columnheaders of `Frequency [kHz],Power [dbm]` and then this `0                           852000,-135.812845793404                                                                                                                                                                                     ...                          852000,-135.2120859201363`

Comment: I think i understand what you want now, edited my first answer

Comment: Well now I'm getting `KeyError: 'Frequency [kHz]'` again...